# C++ Why make new int is error?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Why my code error ?

```
int *x ;
x = new int[5];
x[0] = 3;
x[1] = 4;
x[2] = 5;
x[3] = 1;
x[4] = 2;
x[5] = 11;
x[6] = 90;
int *y ;
y = new int[5];
cout << "if no error, then this command should be run" << endl;
```

but the output is :

> Process exited after 0.07883 seconds with return value 3221226356
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: `new int [5]` and assign `7` values...... where is the problem...??? ;)

Comment: C++ have no bounds checking. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*. End of story.

Answer (score 6):

Before writing code, think of the logic for a moment. If you could allocate space for `5` `int`s and then straightaway carry on storing `10` (or anything beyond 5 elements, for that matter), what's the point of allocating anything, in first place?

What you're seeing here is memory overrun, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). **Don't do that.**

To elaborate, on [0-based indexing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), the valid index for the above case will be 0 to 4, anything beyond that is going to access out of bound memory, which invokes the UB.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate 5 integers then try to store 7.

Why do you expect that to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the 5 and 6 position of an array of length 5.

You only can access x[0], x[1], x[2],x[3] and x[4] positions.

So if an array is of n positions you can access up to position n-1 because the first position is 0.

Answer (score 1):

> Why make new int is error

There is nothing wrong with `make new int`. The problem is with the size of your array at declaration.

Let's look at your code for a moment:

```
int *x ;

x = new int[5];

x[0] = 3;
x[1] = 4;
x[2] = 5;
x[3] = 1;
x[4] = 2;
x[5] = 11;
x[6] = 90;
```

- You start by declaring a pointer int variable in the first line.
- You then assign **exactly** 5 consecutive spaces in memory, with `x` pointing to the first one.
- You then assign values to the 5 blocks of memory, starting at 0 and going up to 4, which is valid, as 0-4 is 5 blocks of memory is what the compiler has initialy allocated for you in memory.
- Then, you try to store 11 in x[5] and 90 in x[6]. This is where undefined behaviour occurs.

When you try to move outside of the index specified in your array, your program is trying to access memory that it should not, because the compiler has only allotted a fixed number of spaces in memory initially. You do not know what the memory space that comes right after `x[4]` has stored in it, if anything at all, because the compiler has only allotted you memory for an array of index 0 to 4. `x[5]` may be empty, in which your program sill continue running, or it may be used in some other process of your machine, and trying to access that is disallowed, which leads to a segmentation fault in your case.

This is why it is called undefined behaviour; when an array index that is outside of the array size declared initially may point to a memory space that is or is not empty. If it is empty, then the program will continue running (**this is wrong**), but if it is *not* empty, then your program will terminate due to a runtime error: segmentation fault.

To fix this, change your array size to:

```
x = new int [7];
```

So that the compiler will find 7 consecutive spaces of memory instead of 5.